# How to get data from multiple tables in dataset?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to display data from XML using dataset in gridview. Now I am getting data in table format. I am able to display data from individual tables but not all table data at once and I have 7 tables to display data from.

Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadData();
}

public void LoadData()
{
    string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/dummy.xml");
    DataSet dsData = new DataSet();
    FileStream fsReadSchema = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
    dsData.ReadXml(fsReadSchema);
    fsReadSchema.Close();
    gv.DataSource = dsData.Tables[4];
    gv.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it correctly - I would combine those seven tables into one - merged, as You know what they contains and what are merging criteria.
Other solution - put seven grids on page and bind each table from dataset individually.